# How to partition a list with N partitions rather than partitions of size N?

Tags: java, list, guava, partitioning

Guava's method, `Lists#partition`, partitions a `List<?>` into a `List<List<?>>` where each partition contains `N` elements (as specified by the second parameters of the function, and excluding the last partition).

Is it possible to use this method but create `N` partitions instead?

If not, what are some ways to go about it?

I've attempted to create `31` partitions with the following (`keys` is a `List<String>` of size `57`), but it only creates `29`:

```
List<String> keys = ...;

var paritions = Lists.partition(keys, (int) Math.ceil(keys.size() / 31D));
```

Comment: Are you tied to using this method in particular for some reason? The splitting itself seems rather straightforward.

Comment: @daniu Nope, I'm just looking for a method to partition a `List<?>` into `N` partitions, but it would be good if the first partitions were filled up first (the last `k` partitions can have fewer elements than the first `N - k`).

Comment: How would you distribute 32 elements in 31 partitions if 30 of them are the same size and only the last one is shorter?

Comment: @Henry The first partition would be of size 2 and the rest would be of size 1.

Comment: That's not what you specified: "where each partition contains N elements (as specified by the second parameters of the function, and excluding the last partition)"

Comment: @Henry I was explaining what Guava's method does.

Comment: Guava doesn't drop the last partition.  It only ever calculates that just-in-time and would give you a partition which isn't even.  It's only ever the last partition which is uneven.

Comment: You asked if you could use that method for your splitting and the answer is clearly no for the given reason.

Comment: @Henry "If not, what are some ways to go about it?"

Comment: what about `List<String> newList = new ArrayList<>();

    newList.addAll(keys.subList(0, 2));

    for (int i = 3; i < keys.size(); i++) {
        newList.add(keys.get(i));
    }`

Comment: @YCF_L I'd rather not hardcode anything, but feel free to post an answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be able to create N partitions, you have to have a minimum of 2N elements.  In your case, you have a partition requirement of 31, which means you'd need 62 elements.

Because you have 57 elements, you're five elements - or two and a half partitions - short of the required minimum, which is why you get 29 partitions, with the last partition only having one element.

Guava is doing its job.  You don't have enough elements to properly subdivide into the partitions you want.

Comment: What would you recommend if I wanted to create `N` partitions and make sure that they're all somewhat filled?

Comment: @JacobG. It depends on what you're trying to achieve. You can append "" as many times as there are missing elements.

Comment: @JacobG.:  If you wanted to do this dynamically, you'd require more data.  Alternatively, you should engineer your code such that it expects *at most* 31 partitions as opposed to *exactly* 31 partitions.  If you mandate that you need 31 partitions, then the code which looks in beyond partitions should be responsible for telling you, "No, there's nothing left."

Comment: @JacobG. of what size?

Comment: I forgotten about the case where I'd have fewer than 31 elements, but I'll just create 31 lists myself in a loop and iterate over `keys` and add to each partition manually.  Thanks!

Comment: Good analysis, partitioning is the wrong tool for this particular job as it defines the group size instead of the number of groups.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that your customized partitioning distributes the "empty space" (i.e. gaps left by a lack of elements to fully fill the partitions) differently than Guava's method. That method will fill each partition completely before creating the next, while you want to evenly distribute the elements. This is because `partition()` defines the **size** of the groups, while you want to specify the **number** of groups.

Look at this custom implementation:

```
private static <T> List<List<T>> distribute(List<T> elements, int nrOfGroups)
{
    int elementsPerGroup = elements.size() / nrOfGroups;
    int leftoverElements = elements.size() % nrOfGroups;

    List<List<T>> groups = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < nrOfGroups; i++)
    {
        groups.add(elements.subList(i * elementsPerGroup + Math.min(i, leftoverElements),
                                    (i + 1) * elementsPerGroup + Math.min(i + 1, leftoverElements)));
    }
    return groups;
}
```

It will calculate the minimum size of the groups (**floor** of count/#groups)  and then correct that for the first few groups in case there are elements left.

**Example**

```
List<Integer> elements = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
int nrOfGroups = 6;
// [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5], [6], [7], [8]]
```